# How to bypass Program Compatibility Assistant in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, acronis-trueimage

### Short version

- **How can I bypass the Program Compatibility Assistant** that blocks some programs from installing?

### Long version

I'm trying to install *Acronis True Image Home 2011* on my Windows 8 Pro. When I execute the installer, I'm getting the following error from *Program Compatibility Assistant*, saying:

> This program has compatibility issues

[image: Program Compatibility Assistant]

I can click *Get help online* for more information, and then they say:

> Acronis True Image has been blocked from running because it might prevent your PC from starting correctly in the future. Your version of Acronis True Image isn't compatible with this version of Windows.

Then my only option is to click *Close* and this aborts the installation. As I have 5 licenses of this program for my home computers, it's annoying that I would have to upgrade to Acronis 2013 just to have Windows 8 compatibility. I'm quite confident that, although I should avoid using functions of Acronis that modify the bootloader, other pieces of software should run just fine. There are probably more programs that at least partially work just fine on Windows 8, but are blocked. So, to summarise, my question is:

**How can I bypass the Program Compatibility Assistant?**

I would simply like that it would allow me to peacefully continue with the installation. An even more generic question would be:

**How does the Program Compatibility Assistant know which programs to block?**

Comment: The short version: you should not use the software in Windows 8 that was blocked from installing. They completely block the installation for a reason.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Acronis directly? Bypassing the installer would be very difficult as the installer program itself has code for approving the installation. I am pretty sure it isn't possible at all.

Comment: I'm sure MS have their reasons to block the installation, but I *want* to proceed anyway. There must be a way to do it!

Comment: I used a program that Compatibility Assistant didn't like, yet it didn't block the installation, it rather warned me. It was an electronic dictionary. It really has issues, but it cannot damage the system. Raymond Chen mentioned in his blog that applications were blocked only if their producer agreed.

Comment: "it might prevent your PC from starting correctly in the future" nuff said. program hard blocks are for a reason

Comment: http://kb.acronis.com/content/31033 Acronis comment on the compatability

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to do it, using the **Local Group Policy Editor**:

1. Press Win+R
2. Run `gpedit.msc`
3. Navigate to: *Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Application Compatibility*
4. Enable both settings:

   - Turn off Application Compatibility Engine
   - Turn off Program Compatibility Assistant

[image: Disabled Settings]

Then the installation executes normally.

Comment: Let us know how it works out.

Comment: The installation completed without problems, rebooted and backing up my system now. I'll try to test the restore feature tomorrow.

Comment: Just a note: This does not work in the Windows 10 Tech Preview, at least as of build 9879.